# getting url parameters in tornado

Tags: rest, api, url, tornado, restful-url

i've been facing some problems in getting url parameters using Tornado web framework.
these are my codes:

```
def main_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/reg", register),
    (r"/account", account),
    ])
```

```
class account(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        name = self.get_argument('name')
        depo = self.get_argument('depo')
        respone = {'name':name ,'depo':depo}
        self.write(respone)
```

i've tried to use some restful API to test this web service.
i  curl a url like `curl localhost:8000/account?name = "parsa" & depo = "10"`
but always i get this error that says it doesn't recognize depo. actually i tested something and it showed that each time the second parameter doesn't work well or even the third one doesn't work.
i tried several ways but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your Tornado code. You are making the curl request incorrectly. You can verify that by visiting that url from your browser.

With, curl, you'll have to wrap the whole url in quotes:

```
curl "localhost:8000/account?name=para&depo=10"
```